# How can I use Directory.CreateDirectory with a different user id?

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to write code to programmatically create a directory (and do other file manipulations) on a server from an application on my workstation -- using Directory.CreateDirectory this would be easy enough, and I know how to do that.  HOWEVER, the problem is that I am trying to do this on a server where my user id doesn't have rights to do so.  I do have an A/D user id to do it with, but I am clueless as to how to use it in my application to do what I need to do (*impersonation* isn't what it's called, but...).

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity ds = new System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity();

// <-- something magic happens here -->

Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\ofmsws42\c$\New_Directory", ds);
```

What goes into the spot where the "magic" happens?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?  I want to say that my credentials for the server end up somewhere in the DirectorySecurity object I am creating, but none of the properties of DirectorySecurity appear to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to impersonate with the account that have permissions in "magic code".

[WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx) have sample (referenced from SO: [How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/impersonation-in-net))

Here are most important chunks of code (`LogonUser` is PInvoke from advapi32.dll):

```
// Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, Console.ReadLine(),
      LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
      out safeTokenHandle);

using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = 
   WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
...
}
```